# multiply text in Emmet using any loop

Tags: emmeans

How do you multiply text in Emmet? For example,

```
div{Some Text} where Some Text repeats in div
div{Some Text*3} and div{Some Text}*3 do not work.
should output

<div>
    Some Text
    Some Text
    Some Text
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you have attached an inappropriate tag [emmeans] to this question...

Answer (score 0):

I had success doing the following:

```
div>{my Text here}*3
```

Which returned:

```
<div>
  my Text here
  my Text here
  my Text here
</div>
```